# Understanding a signal script

Tags: linux, shell-script, signals, trap

I have the following trap script but the idea about it, is little vague to me.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..64}; do
    trap "echo 'signal[$$] Caught signal SIG$(kill -l "$i")($i)'" "$i";
done;

read -s -n1;
```

Comment: So what is your actual question? Where is this from? How is it used and by whom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script does nothing but print which signals it receives.

```
kill -l "$i"
```

replaces the signal number with the name.

I would change this script to

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "My PID is $$"
echo "Send SIGNALS with this command:"
echo "     kill -SIG $$"
echo "SIG may be either a signal name or number, see kill -l"

for i in {1..64}; do
    trap "echo 'signal[$$] Caught signal SIG$(kill -l "$i")($i)'" "$i";
done;

read -s -n1;
```